# Gallery of ImageViews: how to fix the height of the image?

Tags: android, android-image, image-scaling

Thank you for your help and sorry for the dumb questions...

Ok, I have a Gallery displaying different images (I use setImageResource(resId), the Images are jpgs in /drawables).

The images come in different sizes, I would like to have all of them scaled to the same fixed height.

Thanks.

Comment: Just set a specified height to the ImageView.

Comment: @faylon Thanks, this is probably answers that approximate best to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @pietmau. I am really very confused with two answers below. They don't have any relationship with this question. Just specify a fixed height to the ImageView and set scaleType to centerInside, then most images will have the same height. If you want all images have the same height you have to set the ScaleType to CenterCrop or FIT_XY.

Comment: @faylon thank you indeed that is what I have done. And I agree with you that the provided answers have little or no relationship to the question. Thank you very much!